# Text With Superscript In MigraDoc

Tags: c#, pdf, migradoc

I have a class for writing a PDF doc via MigraDoc.

A function makes a call like this:

```
var p = row.Cells[1].AddParagraph();
p.AddLineBreak();
p.AddLineBreak();
_renderHtml(office["Address"], p.AddFormattedText());
```

The _renderHtml code looks like this:

```
private void _renderHtml(string html, FormattedText text)
{
      _renderHtmlElement(
         new Html.Parsable("dom", html),
         text
      );
}
```

The _renderHtmlElement code then does a series of checks for what HTML to actually handle. I'm thinking I should throw it into a switch case, but that doesn't really affect my question. So it looks like this:

```
private void _renderHtmlElement(Html.Element element, FormattedText text)
{
    if ("p" == element.Type)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
    else if ("li" == element.Type)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
    else if ("b" == element.Type || "strong" == element.Type)
    {
        text = text.AddFormattedText(TextFormat.Bold);
    }
    else if ("i" == element.Type || "em" == element.Type)
    {
        text = text.AddFormattedText(TextFormat.Italic);
    }
    else if ("br" == element.Type || "em" == element.Type)
    {
        text.AddLineBreak();
    }
    else if ("text" == element.Type)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
    else if("sup" == element.Type)
    {
        FormattedText ft = text.AddFormattedText(element.ContentDecoded);
        ft.Superscript = true;
    }

    foreach (var child in element.ChildElements)
    {
        _renderHtmlElement(child, text);
    }
}
```

My piece is to get the superscript code working. The code I have in there now will add in the correct content, formatted as a superscript, but it then still has the original content (not superscripted) immediately following it. The methods of `text` seem to only allow add functions, there's no `replace` or `substring` or anything similar for me to just tear out the second instance.

Am I overlooking something obvious here? As you can see from the bold/italic examples, it's a fairly straight forward process, so I would think I'm just not passing in the text.superscript properly.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: How does your HTML class look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add the Superscript text, then you call _renderHtmlElement for the children - maybe a child gives you the same text, but without superscript attribute.
Are there other tags between <sup> and </sup> in your HTML?

MigraDoc has Remove methods so you can remove items - but better not to add them in the first place.

I'd put a breakpoint on "ft.Superscript = true;" and check what _renderHtmlElement does for the children of the "sup" element.

Comment: You were right in thinking a child must be giving the same text. I added into the recursive loop a simple if(element.Type!="sup") and it solved the problem. Thanks!